# scan n numbers without spaces in C

Tags: c, scanf

Suppose n numbers are to be input in a single line without any spaces given the condition that these numbers are subject to the condition that they lie between 1 and 10.

Say n is 6 , then let the input be like "239435"
then if I have an array in which I am storing these numbers then I should get

```
    array[0]=2
    array[1]=3
    array[2]=9
    array[3]=4  
    array[4]=3
```

I can  get the above result by using `array[0]=(input/10^n)` and then the next digit
but is there a simpler way to do it?

Comment: please show us what have you tried?

Comment: If you want numbers ranged from `[0,9]` then you could use a [width specifier of `scanf`](https://www.google.com/search?q=scanf+width+specifier). However you're dealing with `[1,10]`..

Comment: @starrify : `array[0] = (input/10^n)` this leads me to believe that the input will be in range `[0,9]`.

Comment: `scanf("%1d%1d%1d%1d%1d%1d", a,a+1,a+2,a+3,a+4,a+5)`

Comment: @BLUEPIXY : Can you please post your method as the answer? That's the exact answer. I learnt something new today, thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just subtract the ASCII code of `0` for each digit and you get the value of it.

```
 char *s =  "239435"
 int l = strlen(s);
 int *array = malloc(sizeof(int)*l);
 int i;
 for(i = 0; i < l; i++)
      array[i] = s[i]-'0';
```

**update**

Assuming that `0` is not a valid input and only numbers between 1-10 are allowed:

```
 char *s =  "239435"
 int l = strlen(s);
 int *array = malloc(sizeof(int)*l);
 int i = 0;
 while(*s != 0)
 {
      if(!isdigit(*s))
      {
           // error, the user entered something else
      }

      int v = array[i] = *s -'0';

      // If the digit is '0' it should have been '10' and the previous number 
      // has to be adjusted, as it would be '1'. The '0' characater is skipped.
      if(v == 0)
      {
           if(i == 0)
           {
               // Error, first digit was '0'
           }


           // Check if an input was something like '23407'
           if(array[i-1] != 1)
           {
               // Error, invalid number
           }
           array[i-1] = 10;
      }
      else
          array[i] = v;

     s++;
 }
```

Comment: Or better more readable & understandable use `array[i] = s[i] - '0';`

Comment: This will not work in C. You can not declare variable inside for statement.

Comment: @Devolus ... where is the use of `scanf()`? I Mean to say, the OP has tagged the post with scanf. So, asked.

Comment: @SouravGhosh The result of reading a string via `scanf`is ... a string aka `char *`. So why would I need to show the obvious? The poster was asking on how to convert that resulting string to an array, not how to use `scanf` so this is irrelevant for the answer. We don't need to provide full working programs to make an answer helpful, just the relevant parts where a poster has a problem with. At least, that's my take on SO. So is neither a "Let me code that for you" site nor a 101 programming course.

Comment: @Devolus sir, please check the answer by BLUEPIXY, i think my version will be clear to you then. I'm not saying you are wrong, just trying to focus on a better method.

Comment: @SouravGhosh, the answer of BLUEPIXY shows a different approach, so it makes sense to show the `scanf` call there as well. Personally I find this approach not rellay elegant, because you have to pass so many parameters, but of course it is a valid solution as well. I would prefer a more generic solution, which doesn't depend so much on the known number of elements. If the number is longer or shorter you have to update the code as well. For the sake of the answer and provided information it is a suitable answer.

Comment: @Devolus sir, you're right. I accept. One more humbel question, in this approach, what if the string input [by accidental typo] is `"2394e5"` instead of `"239435"`?

Comment: @SouravGhosh, this should indedd be handled, but you would have the same problem with the scanf approach. In my snippet, it could be improved by usign `isdigit(s[i])` and if not then do some error handling. The error handling would look a bit different when using `scanf` but of course it should be done as well.

Comment: another doubt ... say now I have to input numbers which are subject to the condition  1≤A≤10 i.e store in an array numbers 1-10 not 0 or 11.. say the string is 239435105 and array[0]=2, array[1]=2... and array[6]=10 and array[7]=5.

Comment: Before setting the previous number to `10`, you additionaly might check if it is indeed '1' and raise an error (or that you in your case). This would handle an input like `23407`

Answer (score 2):

You can use a string to take the input and then check each position and extact them and store in an array. You need to check for the numeric value in each location explicitly, as you are accepting the input as a string. For integers taken input as string, there's no gurantee that the input is pure numeric and if it is not, things can go wild.

check this code

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()
{
        char ipstring[64];
        int arr[64];
        int count, len = 0;
        printf("Enter the numbersi[not more than 64 numbers]\n");
        scanf("%s", ipstring);
        len = strlen(ipstring);
        for (count = 0; count < len ; count++)
        {
                if (('0'<= ipstring[count]) && (ipstring[count] <= '9'))
                {
                        arr[count] = ipstring[count] - '0';

                }
                else
                {
                        printf("Invalid input detectde in position %d of %s\n", count+1, ipstring );
                        exit(-1);
                }
        }
        //display
        for (count = 0; count < len ; count++)
        {
                printf("arr[%d] = %d\n", count, arr[count]);
        }
        return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

E.g.

```
int a[6];
printf(">");
scanf("%1d%1d%1d%1d%1d%1d", a,a+1,a+2,a+3,a+4,a+5);
printf("%d,%d,%d,%d,%d,%d\n", a[0],a[1],a[2],a[3],a[4],a[5]);
```

result:

```
>239435
2,3,9,4,3,5
```

Comment: thanks for this information sir. Really helpful. One humble question, isn't it better to give some prompt about the count of scanf()? IMHO, for this code, any number entered after the 6th one will be dropped silently.so. . .

Comment: @SouravGhosh This is just a simple example. It is a good idea to such a check of course.